# PLP SIGEP StreamReader Error

Tags: delphi, xml, web-service

Estou integrando em meu sistema o *Webservice* SIGEP, com fechamento de PLP.

Estou com um problema ao postar o XML de fechamento da PLP. Recebo o erro:

> STREAMREADER ERROR

Todas as outras funções funcionam adequadamente. Já tentei de tudo e aparantemente o XML está ok, conforme o manual do Correios.

Alguém, que possui, ou já desenvolveu essa integração, teria como postar um XML de fechamento de PLP como exemplo? Serve o XML das Etiquetas, e/ou o XML de postagem no *webservice*.

No fechamento da PLP, temos a inserção de um XML dentro de outro XML.

Segue exemplo:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:cli="http://cliente.bean.master.sigep.bsb.correios.com.br/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <cli:fechaPlpVariosServicos>
            <xml>
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                <correioslog>
                    <tipo_arquivo>Postagem</tipo_arquivo>
                    <versao_arquivo>2.3</versao_arquivo>
                    <plp>
                        <id_plp />
                        <valor_global></valor_global>
                        <mcu_unidade_postagem></mcu_unidade_postagem>
                        <nome_unidade_postagem></nome_unidade_postagem>
                        <cartao_postagem>********</cartao_postagem>
                    </plp>
                    <remetente>
                        <numero_contrato>**********</numero_contrato>
                        <numero_diretoria>72</numero_diretoria>
                        <codigo_administrativo>********</codigo_administrativo>
                        <nome_remetente>******** *********</nome_remetente>
                        <logradouro_remetente>AVENIDA *******</logradouro_remetente>
                        <numero_remetente>****</numero_remetente>
                        <complemento_remetente></complemento_remetente>
                        <bairro_remetente>********** *****</bairro_remetente>
                        <cep_remetente>********</cep_remetente>
                        <cidade_remetente>RIBEIRAO PRETO</cidade_remetente>
                        <uf_remetente>SP</uf_remetente>
                        <telefone_remetente>16********</telefone_remetente>
                        <fax_remetente></fax_remetente>
                        <email_remetente></email_remetente>
                    </remetente>
                    <forma_pagamento />
                    <objeto_postal>
                        <numero_etiqueta>DU*********BR</numero_etiqueta>
                        <codigo_objeto_cliente />
                        <codigo_servico_postagem>81019</codigo_servico_postagem>
                        <data_captacao/>
                        <cubagem>0</cubagem>
                        <peso>2000</peso>
                        <rt1 />
                        <rt2 />
                        <destinatario>
                            <nome_destinatario>****** ****** ** *****</nome_destinatario>
                            <telefone_destinatario></telefone_destinatario>
                            <celular_destinatario></celular_destinatario>
                            <email_destinatario></email_destinatario>
                            <logradouro_destinatario>*** ******** ***** ** ********* ******</logradouro_destinatario>
                            <complemento_destinatario>14 ANDAR</complemento_destinatario>
                            <numero_end_destinatario>***</numero_end_destinatario>
                        </destinatario>
                        <nacional>
                            <bairro_destinatario>ITAIM BIBI</bairro_destinatario>
                            <cidade_destinatario>SAO PAULO</cidade_destinatario>
                            <uf_destinatario>SP</uf_destinatario>
                            <cep_destinatario>********</cep_destinatario>
                            <codigo_usuario_postal />
                            <centro_custo_cliente />
                            <numero_nota_fiscal>64377</numero_nota_fiscal>
                            <serie_nota_fiscal />
                            <valor_nota_fiscal />
                            <natureza_nota_fiscal />
                            <descricao_objeto></descricao_objeto>
                            <valor_a_cobrar></valor_a_cobrar>
                        </nacional>
                        <servico_adicional>
                            <codigo_servico_adicional>25</codigo_servico_adicional>
                            <codigo_servico_adicional>19</codigo_servico_adicional>
                            <data_agendamento/>
                            <valor_declarado>205,36</valor_declarado>
                        </servico_adicional>
                        <dimensao_objeto>
                            <tipo_objeto>002</tipo_objeto>
                            <dimensao_altura>20,0</dimensao_altura>
                            <dimensao_largura>20,0</dimensao_largura>
                            <dimensao_comprimento>20,0</dimensao_comprimento>
                            <dimensao_diametro></dimensao_diametro>
                        </dimensao_objeto>
                    </objeto_postal>
                </correioslog>
            </xml>
            <idPlpCliente>123</idPlpCliente>
            <cartaoPostagem>**********</cartaoPostagem>
            <listaEtiquetas>DU********BR</listaEtiquetas>
            <usuario>**************</usuario>
            <senha>******</senha>
        </cli:fechaPlpVariosServicos>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque isto não é uma pergunta.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, é bom uma lida no [Tour]. Você não está no site do Emerson (seja lá quem for esse), e aqui não é um site para trocas de contato pessoal (se quiser deixar seu email, cadastre no seu perfil). Se tiver alguma dúvida de programação que não foi respondida ainda no site, e que esteja no [Escopo do site](/help/on-topic), é bem-vindo a [edit] a postagem para adequar sua dúvida. Aqui tem umas dicas: [Ask] e [Help].

Comment: Boa Tarde. Desculpa, como havia achado uma questão relevante de um usuário chamado Emerson e estava no perfil dele, entendi que a questão seria enviada a ele. Quanto ao e-mail percebi que estaria atrelado ao meu cadastro após a conclusão da pergunta, pois meu cadastro foi feito após a conclusão da pergunta. Vou reformular a pergunta e desculpa o inconveniente.

Comment: @MatheusLeone formatei sua postagem, mas não sei se representa a intenção original da sua pergunta. Caso não esteja a contento, fique à vontade para [edit] ou reverter a minha alteração pelo [histórico de edições](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/154986/revisions).

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado pela ajuda. Está ótimo.

Comment: parece ser um erro de codificação UTF-8 vs ANSI, tente fazer uma conversão das strings para UTF-8, quase todos os sistemas internos dos Correios usam UTF-8. Veja uma resposta parecida [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284807/curious-issue-in-delphi-using-stream-reader "Curious issue in Delphi using Stream reader")!